# PowerShell 7.x: Parallel parameter causing problems

Tags: powershell, shell-script

I would like to run the following script in parallel (using PS 7.x) but when I do, it throws-up. If I remove `-Parallel` (line 3) (and `-ThrottleLimit 4` (line 15)) from the script, it works fine - just takes a lot longer to complete. Are there any quick fixes I could make to the script to make it work with `-Parallel` parameter? Thanks!

```
01: $paths=@("O:\OD\OD1\OneDrive\OD1\Photos","O:\OD\FM\OneDrive\FM\Photos")
02: foreach ($path in $paths) {
03:     Get-ChildItem $path\*.tif -recurse | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
04: 
05:         [console]::foregroundcolor="White"   
06:         $basePath=("$path" -replace "\\", "\\")
07:         $origPath=(echo $_.DirectoryName)
08:         $base=(echo $_.BaseName)
09:         $newPath=($origPath -replace "$basePath", "O:\OD\FM\OneDrive\FM\Family Photos")
10:         $newPathAndFile=("$newPath"+"\"+"$base"+".jpg")
11: 
12:         if (!(Test-Path -path "$newPath")) {mkdir "$newPath"}
13:         
14:         if (!([system.io.file]::Exists("$newPathAndFile"))) {magick "$_" -resize 50% -quality 100 -define jpeg:extent=1MB "$newPathAndFile"; [console]::foregroundcolor="Green"; echo "`nComplete`: $newPathAndFile`n"}
15:     } -ThrottleLimit 4
16:     [console]::foregroundcolor="White"
17: }
```

Specifically, I get the following error (note, "line 10" below refers to "line 12" above as it is referencing "line 10" within the second `foreach-object` loop starting on line 3):

[image]

Comment: please remove line numbers from your code [Why is there no line numbering in code sections?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/995714)

Comment: why are you putting double quotes around your $Vars? that should ONLY be done when you need to trigger the `.ToString()` method on an object.

Comment: Why not just use the built-in cmdlets (Test-Path, Write-Host -ForgroundColor White, etc.) vs the full .Net namespaces? Justt curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this refactor...

```
$paths = @('O:\OD\OD1\OneDrive\OD1\Photos','O:\OD\FM\OneDrive\FM\Photos')

foreach ($path in $paths) 
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -FIlter '*.tif' -recurse | 
    ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        [console]::foregroundcolor = 'White'
          
        $basePath       = ($path -replace '\\', '\\')
        $origPath       = (Write-Output $PSitem.DirectoryName)
        $base           = (Write-Output $PSitem.BaseName)
        $newPath        = ($origPath -replace $basePath, 'O:\OD\FM\OneDrive\FM\Family Photos')
        $newPathAndFile = ("$newPath\$base.jpg")

        if (!(Test-Path -path $newPath)) 
        {mkdir $newPath}
        
        if (!([system.io.file]::Exists($newPathAndFile))) 
        {
            magick $PSItem -resize 50% -quality 100 -define jpeg:extent=1MB $newPathAndFile
            [console]::foregroundcolor = Green
            Write-Output "`nComplete`: $newPathAndFile`n"
        }
    } -ThrottleLimit 4

    [console]::foregroundcolor = 'White'
}
```

[PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

[Calling Image Magick from PowerShell](https://www.goingforawalkwiththedogs.com/2017/09/calling-image-magick-from-powershell.html)

> [***Best Practices for aliases***](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/best-practice-for-using-aliases-in-powershell-scripts)
>
> ***Why worry about aliases in the first place?***
>
> What is the big deal about using aliases anyway? If they make the code
> easier to type, what is the harm in using them in scripts?  There are
> two things at work when it comes to a script.  The first is that no
> alias is guaranteed to exist—even aliases that are created by Windows
> PowerShell.
>
> ***The real danger of using an alias in a script...***
>
> But using code such as this really defeats the purpose of using an
> alias.  In the end, it is a best practice to avoid using aliases in
> enterprise production-level scripts.  The same is true when it comes
> to using positional arguments or partial parameter names.
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-powershell-aliases-best-practices
>
> ***When not to use aliases***
>
> With all the goodness that aliases bring to the table, I might be
> inclined to use aliases all the time. There is a disadvantage,
> however. Aliases can be hard to read.
>
> ***Note***
>
> A fundamental tenant of script development is that the better I can
> understand my script, the fewer errors it will contain, and the easier
> it will be to fix any errors that may arise. In addition, because
> scripts are reusable, it also will be easier to modify the script in
> the future. Time spent in script development is an investment in the
> future.

Also of note, both PowerShell PSScriptAnalyzer will call out aliases as errors until you expand them,  as will VSCode.

VSCode has settings to auto expand known aliases and there is an add-on for the PowerShell ISE for the same thing. So, one can dev with aliases and auto-expand before sharing/deployment.